# pip install from local directory - reference path in pip.conf file

Tags: python, pip

I have to setup a directory where wheel files should be downloaded in and installed from, something like a local repository.

I download the wheels like this:

`python3 -m pip download pandas --dest="/opt/app-root/lib/python3.9/downloaded_wheels"`

This works fine and I also found out how to install these wheels from the commandline.

`pip install pandas --no-index --find-links "/opt/app-root/lib/python3.9/downloaded_wheels"`

However this is not the way I want to handle it. I want to run `pip install` and that pip uses the local folder and first priority and the pypi and second priority. I did not find a way to make this work in the pip.conf. Does anyone know how to do this?

Comment: You probably need to deploy and maintain your own private _PyPI_-like server that would act as a proxy/mirror for the real _PyPI_. Something like [_devpi_](https://pypi.org/project/devpi/), but there are other solutions more or less complex to setup.

Comment: [install]
find-links = /opt/app-root/lib/python3.9/downloaded_wheels
Putting this iny my pip.conf works

Comment: Good. But I do not know if this will guarantee the local files as first priority.

Comment: No, but its good enough, since our proxy won´t allow me to download these from another host anyway ;-)